# PID 4 Using Port 80 - IIS Unable To Bind

Tags: iis, port, netstat, iis-8.5

So I've been having a problem where I can't use localhost:80 on IIS

So I ran this:

```
> netstat -ano | find "0:80"
```

And got:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

I then looked under the details tab of Task Manager and PID 4 is "System".
I have no clue what this is or what it does...

Help please?

Answer (score 2):

So after doing a load of research, the fix that worked for me was as follows:

Run: services.msc

Find "Windows Sync Share"

Stop it if running, and set it's startup to disabled.

IIS can now bind to localhost:80

I have see no side effects of stopping the process either.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I don't have a service with that name.

Comment: man.just thank you.i was one step away from suicide.